# React отрисовывает приложение на основе предыдущего состояния

Tags: reactjs

Необходимо реализовать фильтрацию данных (props.data), для этого создана функция getFilteredData(), которая возвращает отфильтрованный массив и передает дальше на отрисовку. Проблема в том, что приложение отрисовывается на основе параметров фильтрации, которые были применены до этого, хотя в стейте находится актуальные значения параметров фильтрации (filterValue, sizeFilterValue)

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import s from './grid.module.css'
import GridItem from "./GridItem/GridItem";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";

const Grid = (props) => {

    let filtrationParams = ({
        categories: [
            {key: 'all', name: 'Все категории'},
            {key: 'animals', name: 'Животные'},
            {key: 'business', name: 'Бизнес'},
            {key: 'food', name: 'Еда'},
            {key: 'health', name: 'Здоровье'},
            {key: 'places', name: 'Места'},
            {key: 'science', name: 'Наука'},
            {key: 'vehicle', name: 'Транспорт'},
            {key: 'winter', name: 'Зима'},
        ]
    })

    const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState('all')
    const [dateFilterValue, setDateFilterValue] = useState()
    const [sizeFilterValue, setSizeFilterValue] = useState()
    const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(props.data);

    let changeSelect = (e) => {
        setFilterValue(e.target.value)

    }
    console.log(filterValue)
    let changeSizeSelect = (e) => {
        setSizeFilterValue(e.target.value)

    }
    console.log(sizeFilterValue)


    let getFilteredData = () => {
        let data = [...props.data]
        if (filterValue === 'all') {

        } else if (filterValue !== 'all') {
            data = data.filter(d => d.category === filterValue)
        }

        if (sizeFilterValue === "ascending") {
            data = data.sort((a, b) => a.filesize > b.filesize ? 1 : -1)
        } else if (sizeFilterValue === "descending") {
            data = data.sort((a, b) => a.filesize - b.filesize)
        }
        return data
    }

// Пагинация

    const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState([]);
    const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
    const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);
    const itemsPerPage = 24

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(getFilteredData())
        const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
        setFiltered(getFilteredData())
        setCurrentItems(filtered.slice(itemOffset, endOffset))
        setPageCount(Math.ceil(filtered.length / itemsPerPage));
    }, [itemOffset, itemsPerPage, filterValue, sizeFilterValue]);
    const handlePageClick = (event) => {
        const newOffset = (event.selected * itemsPerPage) % filtered.length;
        setItemOffset(newOffset);

    };
// Пагинация


    return (
        <div className={s.gridWrapper}>
            <form className={s.selector}>
                <select value={filterValue} onChange={changeSelect}>
                    <option value={'all'}>Все категории</option>
                    <option value={'animals'}>Животные</option>
                    <option value={'business'}>Бизнес</option>
                    <option value={'food'}>Еда</option>
                    <option value={'health'}>Здоровье</option>
                    <option value={'places'}>Места</option>
                    <option value={'science'}>Наука</option>
                    <option value={'vehicle'}>Транспорт</option>
                    <option value={'winter'}>Зима</option>
                </select>
                <select value={sizeFilterValue} onChange={changeSizeSelect}>
                    <option value={"descending"}>По убыванию</option>
                    <option value={"ascending"}>По возрастанию</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <div className={s.gridContainer}>
                {currentItems.map(d => <GridItem image={d.image} filesize={d.filesize} timestamp={d.timestamp}
                                                 category={filtrationParams.categories.filter(category => category.key === d.category)}
                                                 key={d.id}/>)}

            </div>
            <ReactPaginate
                breakLabel="..."
                nextLabel="Далее"
                onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                pageCount={pageCount}
                previousLabel="Назад"
                renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
                containerClassName={s.paginatorContainer}
                previousLinkClassName={s.linkButton}
                nextLinkClassName={s.linkButton}
                activeClassName={s.active}/>
        </div>

    );
};

export default Grid;
```

Comment: Помести вызов следующих функций в useEffect, тогда они будут гарантированно получать актуальный стейт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что в вашем useEffect

```
setFiltered(getFilteredData())
setCurrentItems(filtered.slice(itemOffset, endOffset))
```

состояние `filtered` находится еще предыдущее, т.к. операции изменения состояния асинхронные.
Как вариант, вынести в отдельный `useEffect` операцию изменения данных и поставить слушатель на переменную `filtered`. Как только значения фильтра поменяются, поменяются и значения `currentItems`

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import s from './grid.module.css'
import GridItem from "./GridItem/GridItem";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";

const Grid = (props) => {

    let filtrationParams = ({
        categories: [
            {key: 'all', name: 'Все категории'},
            {key: 'animals', name: 'Животные'},
            {key: 'business', name: 'Бизнес'},
            {key: 'food', name: 'Еда'},
            {key: 'health', name: 'Здоровье'},
            {key: 'places', name: 'Места'},
            {key: 'science', name: 'Наука'},
            {key: 'vehicle', name: 'Транспорт'},
            {key: 'winter', name: 'Зима'},
        ]
    })

    const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState('all')
    const [dateFilterValue, setDateFilterValue] = useState()
    const [sizeFilterValue, setSizeFilterValue] = useState()
    const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(props.data);

    let changeSelect = (e) => {
        setFilterValue(e.target.value)

    }
    console.log(filterValue)
    let changeSizeSelect = (e) => {
        setSizeFilterValue(e.target.value)

    }
    console.log(sizeFilterValue)


    let getFilteredData = () => {
        let data = [...props.data]
        if (filterValue === 'all') {

        } else if (filterValue !== 'all') {
            data = data.filter(d => d.category === filterValue)
        }

        if (sizeFilterValue === "ascending") {
            data = data.sort((a, b) => a.filesize > b.filesize ? 1 : -1)
        } else if (sizeFilterValue === "descending") {
            data = data.sort((a, b) => a.filesize - b.filesize)
        }
        return data
    }

// Пагинация

    const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState([]);
    const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
    const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);
    const itemsPerPage = 24

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(getFilteredData())
        //const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
        setFiltered(getFilteredData())
        //setCurrentItems(filtered.slice(itemOffset, endOffset))
        //setPageCount(Math.ceil(filtered.length / itemsPerPage));
    }, [/*itemOffset, itemsPerPage,*/ filterValue, sizeFilterValue]);
    const handlePageClick = (event) => {
        const newOffset = (event.selected * itemsPerPage) % filtered.length;
        setItemOffset(newOffset);

    };
// Пагинация

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(filtered);
        const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
        setCurrentItems(filtered.slice(itemOffset, endOffset));
        setPageCount(Math.ceil(filtered.length / itemsPerPage));
    }, [filtered, itemOffset]);


    return (
        <div className={s.gridWrapper}>
            <form className={s.selector}>
                <select value={filterValue} onChange={changeSelect}>
                    <option value={'all'}>Все категории</option>
                    <option value={'animals'}>Животные</option>
                    <option value={'business'}>Бизнес</option>
                    <option value={'food'}>Еда</option>
                    <option value={'health'}>Здоровье</option>
                    <option value={'places'}>Места</option>
                    <option value={'science'}>Наука</option>
                    <option value={'vehicle'}>Транспорт</option>
                    <option value={'winter'}>Зима</option>
                </select>
                <select value={sizeFilterValue} onChange={changeSizeSelect}>
                    <option value={"descending"}>По убыванию</option>
                    <option value={"ascending"}>По возрастанию</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <div className={s.gridContainer}>
                {currentItems.map(d => <GridItem image={d.image} filesize={d.filesize} timestamp={d.timestamp}
                                                 category={filtrationParams.categories.filter(category => category.key === d.category)}
                                                 key={d.id}/>)}

            </div>
            <ReactPaginate
                breakLabel="..."
                nextLabel="Далее"
                onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                pageCount={pageCount}
                previousLabel="Назад"
                renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
                containerClassName={s.paginatorContainer}
                previousLinkClassName={s.linkButton}
                nextLinkClassName={s.linkButton}
                activeClassName={s.active}/>
        </div>

    );
};

export default Grid;
```